# Manually Reading in Data in SAS from CSV

Tags: sas

So I have a large dataset that is rather oddly formatted and I want to read it in based on the header. It only has unique columns for each unique participant and each participant participated in multiple rounds of the study. The data is from some experiments and is formatted as having variables for each participant (e.g. "participant.code") then some session variables which I can drop and then the actual variables from the experiment. These are formatted as "study.[round number].player.[variable]"

Rather then repeating the variable for every round, I want to just take out the round number as a separate variable and have an observation for every round for each participant.

I want to read these in differently depending on the variable and pick it out. I would rather not have to manually mess with the source file since the experiment is going to be run multiple times.

If someone could just point me towards some relevant material or whatnot that would be great.

Thank you!

Edit: example of some of the raw data:

```
participant.id_in_session,participant.code,participant.label,participant._is_bot,participant._index_in_pages,participant._max_page_index,participant._current_app_name,participant._current_page_name,participant.time_started_utc,participant.visited,participant.mturk_worker_id,participant.mturk_assignment_id,participant.payoff,session.code,session.label,session.mturk_HITId,session.mturk_HITGroupId,session.comment,session.is_demo,session.config.real_world_currency_per_point,session.config.participation_fee,session.config.name,session.config.treatment,study.1.player.id_in_group,study.1.player.role,study.1.player.payoff,study.1.player.Seatfinal,study.1.player.finalpay,study.1.player.payroundpay,study.1.player.QCorrect,study.1.player.treatment,study.1.player.Q1a,study.1.player.Q1b,study.1.player.Q1c,study.1.player.Q2a,study.1.player.Q3,study.1.player.Q4,study.1.player.Q5,study.1.player.Q6,study.1.player.Q7,study.1.player.Q80,study.1.player.Q81,study.1.player.Q82,study.1.player.offer,study.1.player.OfferNum,study.1.player.OfferTaken,study.1.player.BuyerNumber,study.1.player.Seatnum2,study.1.player.Seatnum,study.1.player.pay,study.1.player.isoffertaken,study.1.player.hastakenoffer,study.1.player.consent,study.1.player.offerPrice,study.1.player.oprice,study.1.player.guess_num_seller,study.1.player.BoughtPrice,study.1.player.reward,study.1.player.guess_num_buyer,study.1.group.id_in_subsession,study.1.subsession.round_number,study.1.subsession.offersrem,study.1.subsession.game_finished,study.1.subsession.numbuyers,study.1.subsession.bnum,study.1.subsession.payround,study.2.player.id_in_group,study.2.player.role,study.2.player.payoff,study.2.player.Seatfinal,study.2.player.finalpay,study.2.player.payroundpay,study.2.player.QCorrect,study.2.player.treatment,study.2.player.Q1a,study.2.player.Q1b,study.2.player.Q1c,study.2.player.Q2a,study.2.player.Q3,study.2.player.Q4,study.2.player.Q5,study.2.player.Q6,study.2.player.Q7,study.2.player.Q80,study.2.player.Q81,study.2.player.Q82,study.2.player.offer,study.2.player.OfferNum,study.2.player.OfferTaken,study.2.player.BuyerNumber,study.2.player.Seatnum2,study.2.player.Seatnum,study.2.player.pay,study.2.player.isoffertaken,study.2.player.hastakenoffer,study.2.player.consent,study.2.player.offerPrice,study.2.player.oprice,study.2.player.guess_num_seller,study.2.player.BoughtPrice,study.2.player.reward,study.2.player.guess_num_buyer,study.2.group.id_in_subsession,study.2.subsession.round_number,study.2.subsession.offersrem,study.2.subsession.game_finished,study.2.subsession.numbuyers,study.2.subsession.bnum,study.2.subsession.payround,study.3.player.id_in_group,study.3.player.role,study.3.player.payoff,study.3.player.Seatfinal,study.3.player.finalpay,study.3.player.payroundpay,study.3.player.QCorrect,study.3.player.treatment,study.3.player.Q1a,study.3.player.Q1b,study.3.player.Q1c,study.3.player.Q2a,study.3.player.Q3,study.3.player.Q4,study.3.player.Q5,study.3.player.Q6,study.3.player.Q7,study.3.player.Q80,study.3.player.Q81,study.3.player.Q82,study.3.player.offer,study.3.player.OfferNum,study.3.player.OfferTaken,study.3.player.BuyerNumber,study.3.player.Seatnum2,study.3.player.Seatnum,study.3.player.pay,study.3.player.isoffertaken,study.3.player.hastakenoffer,study.3.player.consent,study.3.player.offerPrice,study.3.player.oprice,study.3.player.guess_num_seller,study.3.player.BoughtPrice,study.3.player.reward,study.3.player.guess_num_buyer,study.3.group.id_in_subsession,study.3.subsession.round_number,study.3.subsession.offersrem,study.3.subsession.game_finished,study.3.subsession.numbuyers,study.3.subsession.bnum,study.3.subsession.payround,study.4.player.id_in_group,study.4.player.role,study.4.player.payoff,study.4.player.Seatfinal,study.4.player.finalpay,study.4.player.payroundpay,study.4.player.QCorrect,study.4.player.treatment,study.4.player.Q1a,study.4.player.Q1b,study.4.player.Q1c,study.4.player.Q2a,study.4.player.Q3,study.4.player.Q4,study.4.player.Q5,study.4.player.Q6,study.4.player.Q7,study.4.player.Q80,study.4.player.Q81,study.4.player.Q82,study.4.player.offer,study.4.player.OfferNum,study.4.player.OfferTaken,study.4.player.BuyerNumber,study.4.player.Seatnum2,study.4.player.Seatnum,study.4.player.pay,study.4.player.isoffertaken,study.4.player.hastakenoffer,study.4.player.consent,study.4.player.offerPrice,study.4.player.oprice,study.4.player.guess_num_seller,study.4.player.BoughtPrice,study.4.player.reward,study.4.player.guess_num_buyer,study.4.group.id_in_subsession,study.4.subsession.round_number,study.4.subsession.offersrem,study.4.subsession.game_finished,study.4.subsession.numbuyers,study.4.subsession.bnum,study.4.subsession.payround,study.5.player.id_in_group,study.5.player.role,study.5.player.payoff,study.5.player.Seatfinal,study.5.player.finalpay,study.5.player.payroundpay,study.5.player.QCorrect,study.5.player.treatment,study.5.player.Q1a,study.5.player.Q1b,study.5.player.Q1c,study.5.player.Q2a,study.5.player.Q3,study.5.player.Q4,study.5.player.Q5,study.5.player.Q6,study.5.player.Q7,study.5.player.Q80,study.5.player.Q81,study.5.player.Q82,study.5.player.offer,study.5.player.OfferNum,study.5.player.OfferTaken,study.5.player.BuyerNumber,study.5.player.Seatnum2,study.5.player.Seatnum,study.5.player.pay,study.5.player.isoffertaken,study.5.player.hastakenoffer,study.5.player.consent,study.5.player.offerPrice,study.5.player.oprice,study.5.player.guess_num_seller,study.5.player.BoughtPrice,study.5.player.reward,study.5.player.guess_num_buyer,study.5.group.id_in_subsession,study.5.subsession.round_number,study.5.subsession.offersrem,study.5.subsession.game_finished,study.5.subsession.numbuyers,study.5.subsession.bnum,study.5.subsession.payround,study.6.player.id_in_group,study.6.player.role,study.6.player.payoff,study.6.player.Seatfinal,study.6.player.finalpay,study.6.player.payroundpay,study.6.player.QCorrect,study.6.player.treatment,study.6.player.Q1a,study.6.player.Q1b,study.6.player.Q1c,study.6.player.Q2a,study.6.player.Q3,study.6.player.Q4,study.6.player.Q5,study.6.player.Q6,study.6.player.Q7,study.6.player.Q80,study.6.player.Q81,study.6.player.Q82,study.6.player.offer,study.6.player.OfferNum,study.6.player.OfferTaken,study.6.player.BuyerNumber,study.6.player.Seatnum2,study.6.player.Seatnum,study.6.player.pay,study.6.player.isoffertaken,study.6.player.hastakenoffer,study.6.player.consent,study.6.player.offerPrice,study.6.player.oprice,study.6.player.guess_num_seller,study.6.player.BoughtPrice,study.6.player.reward,study.6.player.guess_num_buyer,study.6.group.id_in_subsession,study.6.subsession.round_number,study.6.subsession.offersrem,study.6.subsession.game_finished,study.6.subsession.numbuyers,study.6.subsession.bnum,study.6.subsession.payround,study.7.player.id_in_group,study.7.player.role,study.7.player.payoff,study.7.player.Seatfinal,study.7.player.finalpay,study.7.player.payroundpay,study.7.player.QCorrect,study.7.player.treatment,study.7.player.Q1a,study.7.player.Q1b,study.7.player.Q1c,study.7.player.Q2a,study.7.player.Q3,study.7.player.Q4,study.7.player.Q5,study.7.player.Q6,study.7.player.Q7,study.7.player.Q80,study.7.player.Q81,study.7.player.Q82,study.7.player.offer,study.7.player.OfferNum,study.7.player.OfferTaken,study.7.player.BuyerNumber,study.7.player.Seatnum2,study.7.player.Seatnum,study.7.player.pay,study.7.player.isoffertaken,study.7.player.hastakenoffer,study.7.player.consent,study.7.player.offerPrice,study.7.player.oprice,study.7.player.guess_num_seller,study.7.player.BoughtPrice,study.7.player.reward,study.7.player.guess_num_buyer,study.7.group.id_in_subsession,study.7.subsession.round_number,study.7.subsession.offersrem,study.7.subsession.game_finished,study.7.subsession.numbuyers,study.7.subsession.bnum,study.7.subsession.payround,study.8.player.id_in_group,study.8.player.role,study.8.player.payoff,study.8.player.Seatfinal,study.8.player.finalpay,study.8.player.payroundpay,study.8.player.QCorrect,study.8.player.treatment,study.8.player.Q1a,study.8.player.Q1b,study.8.player.Q1c,study.8.player.Q2a,study.8.player.Q3,study.8.player.Q4,study.8.player.Q5,study.8.player.Q6,study.8.player.Q7,study.8.player.Q80,study.8.player.Q81,study.8.player.Q82,study.8.player.offer,study.8.player.OfferNum,study.8.player.OfferTaken,study.8.player.BuyerNumber,study.8.player.Seatnum2,study.8.player.Seatnum,study.8.player.pay,study.8.player.isoffertaken,study.8.player.hastakenoffer,study.8.player.consent,study.8.player.offerPrice,study.8.player.oprice,study.8.player.guess_num_seller,study.8.player.BoughtPrice,study.8.player.reward,study.8.player.guess_num_buyer,study.8.group.id_in_subsession,study.8.subsession.round_number,study.8.subsession.offersrem,study.8.subsession.game_finished,study.8.subsession.numbuyers,study.8.subsession.bnum,study.8.subsession.payround,study.9.player.id_in_group,study.9.player.role,study.9.player.payoff,study.9.player.Seatfinal,study.9.player.finalpay,study.9.player.payroundpay,study.9.player.QCorrect,study.9.player.treatment,study.9.player.Q1a,study.9.player.Q1b,study.9.player.Q1c,study.9.player.Q2a,study.9.player.Q3,study.9.player.Q4,study.9.player.Q5,study.9.player.Q6,study.9.player.Q7,study.9.player.Q80,study.9.player.Q81,study.9.player.Q82,study.9.player.offer,study.9.player.OfferNum,study.9.player.OfferTaken,study.9.player.BuyerNumber,study.9.player.Seatnum2,study.9.player.Seatnum,study.9.player.pay,study.9.player.isoffertaken,study.9.player.hastakenoffer,study.9.player.consent,study.9.player.offerPrice,study.9.player.oprice,study.9.player.guess_num_seller,study.9.player.BoughtPrice,study.9.player.reward,study.9.player.guess_num_buyer,study.9.group.id_in_subsession,study.9.subsession.round_number,study.9.subsession.offersrem,study.9.subsession.game_finished,study.9.subsession.numbuyers,study.9.subsession.bnum,study.9.subsession.payround,study.10.player.id_in_group,study.10.player.role,study.10.player.payoff,study.10.player.Seatfinal,study.10.player.finalpay,study.10.player.payroundpay,study.10.player.QCorrect,study.10.player.treatment,study.10.player.Q1a,study.10.player.Q1b,study.10.player.Q1c,study.10.player.Q2a,study.10.player.Q3,study.10.player.Q4,study.10.player.Q5,study.10.player.Q6,study.10.player.Q7,study.10.player.Q80,study.10.player.Q81,study.10.player.Q82,study.10.player.offer,study.10.player.OfferNum,study.10.player.OfferTaken,study.10.player.BuyerNumber,study.10.player.Seatnum2,study.10.player.Seatnum,study.10.player.pay,study.10.player.isoffertaken,study.10.player.hastakenoffer,study.10.player.consent,study.10.player.offerPrice,study.10.player.oprice,study.10.player.guess_num_seller,study.10.player.BoughtPrice,study.10.player.reward,study.10.player.guess_num_buyer,study.10.group.id_in_subsession,study.10.subsession.round_number,study.10.subsession.offersrem,study.10.subsession.game_finished,study.10.subsession.numbuyers,study.10.subsession.bnum,study.10.subsession.payround,study.11.player.id_in_group,study.11.player.role,study.11.player.payoff,study.11.player.Seatfinal,study.11.player.finalpay,study.11.player.payroundpay,study.11.player.QCorrect,study.11.player.treatment,study.11.player.Q1a,study.11.player.Q1b,study.11.player.Q1c,study.11.player.Q2a,study.11.player.Q3,study.11.player.Q4,study.11.player.Q5,study.11.player.Q6,study.11.player.Q7,study.11.player.Q80,study.11.player.Q81,study.11.player.Q82,study.11.player.offer,study.11.player.OfferNum,study.11.player.OfferTaken,study.11.player.BuyerNumber,study.11.player.Seatnum2,study.11.player.Seatnum,study.11.player.pay,study.11.player.isoffertaken,study.11.player.hastakenoffer,study.11.player.consent,study.11.player.offerPrice,study.11.player.oprice,study.11.player.guess_num_seller,study.11.player.BoughtPrice,study.11.player.reward,study.11.player.guess_num_buyer,study.11.group.id_in_subsession,study.11.subsession.round_number,study.11.subsession.offersrem,study.11.subsession.game_finished,study.11.subsession.numbuyers,study.11.subsession.bnum,study.11.subsession.payround,study.12.player.id_in_group,study.12.player.role,study.12.player.payoff,study.12.player.Seatfinal,study.12.player.finalpay,study.12.player.payroundpay,study.12.player.QCorrect,study.12.player.treatment,study.12.player.Q1a,study.12.player.Q1b,study.12.player.Q1c,study.12.player.Q2a,study.12.player.Q3,study.12.player.Q4,study.12.player.Q5,study.12.player.Q6,study.12.player.Q7,study.12.player.Q80,study.12.player.Q81,study.12.player.Q82,study.12.player.offer,study.12.player.OfferNum,study.12.player.OfferTaken,study.12.player.BuyerNumber,study.12.player.Seatnum2,study.12.player.Seatnum,study.12.player.pay,study.12.player.isoffertaken,study.12.player.hastakenoffer,study.12.player.consent,study.12.player.offerPrice,study.12.player.oprice,study.12.player.guess_num_seller,study.12.player.BoughtPrice,study.12.player.reward,study.12.player.guess_num_buyer,study.12.group.id_in_subsession,study.12.subsession.round_number,study.12.subsession.offersrem,study.12.subsession.game_finished,study.12.subsession.numbuyers,study.12.subsession.bnum,study.12.subsession.payround,study.13.player.id_in_group,study.13.player.role,study.13.player.payoff,study.13.player.Seatfinal,study.13.player.finalpay,study.13.player.payroundpay,study.13.player.QCorrect,study.13.player.treatment,study.13.player.Q1a,study.13.player.Q1b,study.13.player.Q1c,study.13.player.Q2a,study.13.player.Q3,study.13.player.Q4,study.13.player.Q5,study.13.player.Q6,study.13.player.Q7,study.13.player.Q80,study.13.player.Q81,study.13.player.Q82,study.13.player.offer,study.13.player.OfferNum,study.13.player.OfferTaken,study.13.player.BuyerNumber,study.13.player.Seatnum2,study.13.player.Seatnum,study.13.player.pay,study.13.player.isoffertaken,study.13.player.hastakenoffer,study.13.player.consent,study.13.player.offerPrice,study.13.player.oprice,study.13.player.guess_num_seller,study.13.player.BoughtPrice,study.13.player.reward,study.13.player.guess_num_buyer,study.13.group.id_in_subsession,study.13.subsession.round_number,study.13.subsession.offersrem,study.13.subsession.game_finished,study.13.subsession.numbuyers,study.13.subsession.bnum,study.13.subsession.payround

1,kppf7hjb,,0,221,221,study,FinalPay,2022-04-16 22:08:18.471115,1,,,0.0,lew8kph3,,,,,0,1.0,0.0,externality_control,0,2,Seller,0.0,1,0,0,10,0,125,125,50,100,50,0,0,0,1,1,,,1,3,,0,1,1,100,0,0,,50.0,,,,,,1,1,6,1,5,6,4,2,Seller,0.0,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,1,,0,,,100,0,0,,45.0,,,,,,1,2,6,1,5,6,13,2,Seller,0.0,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,,0,,,100,0,0,,,,,,,,1,3,5,1,5,6,6,2,Seller,0.0,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,6,,0,,,138,1,0,,38.0,,,,,,1,4,6,1,5,6,3,2,Seller,0.0,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,2,,0,,,135,1,0,,35.0,,,,,,1,5,6,1,5,6,11,2,Seller,0.0,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,0,0,,0,,,100,0,0,,,,,,,,1,6,5,1,5,6,6,2,Seller,0.0,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,6,,0,,,132,1,0,,32.0,,,,,,1,7,6,1,5,6,4,2,Seller,0.0,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,5,,0,,,150,1,0,,50.0,,,,,,1,8,6,1,5,6,9,2,Seller,0.0,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,2,,0,,,100,0,0,,49.0,,,,,,1,9,6,1,5,6,10,2,Seller,0.0,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,5,,0,,,100,0,0,,39.0,,,,,,1,10,6,1,5,6,3,2,Seller,0.0,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,1,,0,,,132,1,0,,32.0,,,,,,1,11,6,1,5,6,10,2,Seller,0.0,,0,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,1,,0,,,130,1,0,,30.0,,,,,,1,12,6,1,5,6,8,2,Seller,0.0,1,192,132,10,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,1,2,,0,,,128,1,0,,28.0,,,,,,1,13,6,1,5,6,11
```

Comment: Please show an example of the text of the text file you are trying to read.  Just a few rows and values per row, enough to demonstrate the issue.  If it is really a CSV file then just write a data step to read it. You can name the variables anything you want, you are not limited to only using the text from the header line in the file for the variable names.

Comment: @Tom Thank you, I added in the first two lines of the raw data, hopefully it will give you an idea of what the issue is. Each participant takes part in 13 rounds. At the moment, each round has a unique set of each variable, I want to drop these into new observations. Also, a lot of the variables are not really relevant and don't need to be read in.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. It's solvable in SAS. There are a lot of ways to go about it. I'll be interested in seeing what other people come up with.

Comment: You posted a line with 582 columns. The headers are as short as 12 characters and as long as 44.  They have few are 2 dot separated words and as many as 4.  Do you just have one of these files?  What do the different rows represent?  Or do you have different files with a different set of headers?

Comment: @Tom yes. that is precisely the issue I was having. Each row is a participant in an experiment. Each participant engages in multiple rounds. For each round, it generates a new set of variables for the participant, each of these appears in the header. For example, study.1.player.pay is the variable "pay" in round 1. "player" indicates the variable is saved at the player level. study.2.player.pay is the variable "pay" in round 2.

Comment: @Tom also, I have more than one of these files, these datafiles are the raw output of the experiment after each session performing the test.

Comment: Do all of the files have the same number of columns?  Is every "study" repeated 13 times like in your first example.

Comment: @Tom yes to both questions. Though, ideally, I would want to be able to accommodate some minor changes in the columns without everything breaking (I am handing it over and there are plans to edit the experiment going forward).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is not really as complicated as it first seems.  For example the bulk of the data is just 43 columns that repeat 13 times. The STUDY.1 columns, then STUDY.2 columns etc.

For this one just write a program to read it.  There are 22 columns that are not "study" columns.  Then 13 copies of the 43 study columns.

```
data want;
  infile csv dsd truncover firstobs=2;
  input var1 ..... var22 @;
  do study=1 to 13;
    input svar1 .... svar43 @ ;
    output;
  end;
run;
```

So you turn each line into 13 observations (study=1 to study=13).

To complete the sketch of a data step above you just need figure out want names you want to use for the 65 (22 + 43) variables other than STUDY. And for each variable what type of variable it is, numeric or character, and when character what length it needs to store the longest possible value.

If you need to work with a lot of different variations of files in this style then it might be worth working on a program to analyze the headers and determine the role of the columns based on the pattern of the header name and perhaps generate the code to read the file.

You might start by building a dataset with just the header names.

```
data headers;
  infile csv dsd obs=1 ;
  length col 8 words 8 ;
  col+1;
  array header [4] $50 ;
  input header1 :$50. @@ ;
  words=countw(header1,'.');
  do _n_=words to 1 by -1;
    header[_n_] = scan(header1,_n_,'.');
  end;
run;
```

You can use that list of the headers to help you figure out what would be useful names for the variables.

If you want to let SAS guess how to define and name the variables you could try splitting the CSV file into two separate CSV files.  One with the first 22 columns and one with the other 43.  So first split the headers (perhaps removing the STUDY.N. prefix while you are at it). Then split the data. Add an ROW number to make it easy to join them later.

```
filename single temp;
filename multiple temp;

data _null_;
   infile csv dsd obs=1 ;
   input header :$50. @@ ;
   file single dsd ;
   if _n_=1 then put 'ROW,' @;
   if _n_<= 22 then put header @;
   else do;
     file multiple dsd;
     if _n_=23 then put 'ROW,STUDY,'@ ;
     call scan(header,3,pos,len,'.');
     header = substr(header,pos);
     put header @;
   end;
   if _n_=22+43 then stop;
run;

data _null_;
   infile csv dsd firstobs=2 truncover ;
   row+1;
   length s1-s43 $200 ;
   input s1-s22 @;
   file single dsd mod;
   put row s1-s22 ;
   file multiple dsd mod;
   do study=1 to 13 ;
     input s1-s43 @ ;
     put row study s1-s43 ;
   end;
run;
```

Now you can use PROC IMPORT to GUESS how to read SINGLE and MULTIPLE and then you can join them back together.

```
proc import file=single dbms=csv out=single replace;
run;
proc import file=multiple dbms=csv out=multiple replace;
run;

data want;
  merge single multiple;
  by row;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a lot of help. Just a few things. Would it be possible to 'skip' over some of them and drop them selectively? I could do this more or less manually, but also being able to dump the ones that are null (for all participants) might be easier.

Comment: You cannot really SKIP anything when reading the text file (other than variables that are on the ends of the lines) since to know where column 10 starts you have to read columns 1 to 9 first. But you can DROP any variable you do not want to keep.  And DELETE the observation for any "STUDY" that just has all missing values.

Comment: If there are whole columns you don't want to bother with just read those into a dummy character variable and drop that variable.  So if you want only the 5th 6th and 10th value from a line use:  `length dummy $1; input 4*dummy var5 var6 3*dummy var10; drop dummy;`

Comment: thank you! I am probably just being foolish, but how would I go about calling the header portions to name the variables? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Code generation.  Via macro code, CALL EXECUTE() or simply using PUT statement to write the code to text file you then execute via %INCLUDE statement.  But unless you have hundreds of these studies with each one asking different questions it is not really worth it here.  Unless you have access to much richer metadata about the design than the simple headers in the CSV file. Such as order they will appear in the file, type, length etc.